# unknotted $n$-dimensional knot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $n$ be any integer. An $n$-dimensional knot is an $n$-dimensional manifold embedded smoothly into $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. If it is homeomorphic to a disjoint union of $n$-spheres, then it is denoted by $S^n$-knot. The $2$-dimensional knot is called surface-knot. I am asking how to define trivial or unknotted $n$-dimensional knot in general. I know how to define for special cases. For example, $S^n$-knot is called unknotted if it is obtained from some standard $n$-spheres in $(n+2)$-space. In addition a surface-knot is trivial if it is obtained from some disjoint standard surfaces in 4-space by taking a connected sum. Suppose the case where we have n-dim knot which is not homeomorphich to n-sphere and $n \neq 2$ then how to define unknotted type in this case?

Comment: A classical knot, or a 1 dimensional knot, is trivial if it is ambient isotopic to the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$.  In the case where we have a knotted $n$-sphere, we just add $n-1$ to all the dimensions I mentioned.  But there is no reason a generic $n$-dim'l manifold will need to embedd in $n+2$.  Whitney's Embedding theorem gives us the best possible dimension as $2n$.  So your manifold needs more conditions on it, before we can really talk about being knotted.

Answer (score 1):

An oriented $n-$dimensional manifold embedded in $S^{n+2}$ is unknotted if it is homeomorphic to an embedding of that manifold in $S^{n+1}\times \{0\}$.

You can look at this [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970901?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) for more discussion.